# Flutter Communication Between Widgets Using Static StreamController

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm studying Flutter and got into a situation where I can't think of a better approach.
There is a calendar that I built. When I tap on the day Widget, it should update its week. The problem is that the week might be in different months and sometimes, different years.
What I currently have is a static `StreamController` in the Calendar Widget and every Week listen for it and update it if necessary. However, I feel like this is not the best approach as I can't close the Calendar `StreamControler` when it is not rendering.

In this example, if I tap on Feb, 27 or Mar, 3, it should update both weeks as chronologically, they are the same.

[image: widgets]

```
class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  static var dayUpdated = StreamController<DateTime>.broadcast();
  ...
}
```

```
class _WeekState extends State<Week> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Calendar.dayUpdated.stream.listen((date) {
      if (weekFirstDay.isBefore(date) && weekLastDay.isAfter(date)) {
        checkForObjective();
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

```
class _DayCellState extends State<DayCell> {

  void toggleDay() {
    ...
    Calendar.dayUpdated.add(DateTime(widget.year, widget.month, widget.day));
  }
}
```